# How to bundle dictionary data(meanings, examples, reference) into an android app

Tags: android, dictionary, 7zip

I am building a dictionary app for android. My biggest issue/problems is to compress the dictionary data(examples, meanings, e.t.c) into a format that is both fast to search and extract for displaying.

Currently i just zip small chunks of it into a .7z format which is bad for extraction.
Like all words starting with a into A.7z, b into b.7z, e.t.c

How do dictionary apps like [Livio's English Dictionary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=livio.pack.lang.en_US&hl=en&gl=US) do it.
Livio is using the files `pdict6c.jet` and `pdict6i.ser`. What are these file format and how can i generate them.

I am also extracting my data from the wikitionary.

PS: Compressing this data is very important in order to not take up too much space on the user's device.

Answer (score 0):

You can't search a zipped file. Besides, Android Studio automatically zips files when bundling them into an APK/ABI file for release. That means there's no point in you zipping the file.

The app you mention contains a 37MB dictionary file of some sort. I have no idea what this file is, but I assume it's just a [built-in Sqlite database](https://www.google.com/search?q=android%20sqlite%20database%20in%20assets&client=firefox-b-1-d&biw=2560&bih=1296&sxsrf=ALiCzsZqqZ13PCBl4sBnJt2brJPP_WcE0A%3A1655262014972&ei=PkupYtfcOoaZkPIPjYiuqAw&ved=0ahUKEwjX86XDu674AhWGDEQIHQ2EC8U4ChDh1QMIDQ&uact=5&oq=android%20sqlite%20database%20in%20assets&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEB4QFjIFCAAQhgMyBQgAEIYDOgcIIxCwAxAnOgcIABBHELADOggIABAeEA8QBzoGCAAQHhAIOgYIABAeEAc6CAgAEB4QCBAHOgUIABCABDoICAAQHhAPEBY6BQghEKABOgUIIRCrAjoICCEQHhAWEB1KBAhBGABKBAhGGABQuwpY6Edg20hoBXABeACAAYACiAGaEJIBBjEuMTIuMpgBAKABAcgBCcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz). This disk size is consistent with what one would expect for such a file.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but you can 7z a folder and drop it in the assets folder of your project thereby reducing the overall size. Then open it in memory(RAM) with `context.assets.open()`.

Comment: I examine Livio's app and as you can see it is using a different compression/file format. All the app's data are in `pdict6c.jet` and `pdict6i.ser`. I wanna know what it is, what are these file formats and how to generate them?.

Comment: Try actually generating the APK or app bundle (ABI file) both with and without using 7zip compression. Because you're just comparing the sizes of the project files, but that's not what the end user will be downloading. I'm guessing the .jet and .ser files are extensions that Android's build process assigns to assets. My guess is those are actually be .db and .wal files.